# Compare date less than 3 months

Tags: c#, date

I need to compare whether date is less than 3 months old.

I will get installation date:

```
DateTime installdate=DateTime.Parse("1/5/2012 8:12:14 PM");
if ((installdate<DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3)))
{
  // do something
}
```

Is this the best way to compare the dates?

Thanks.

Comment: First of all, define what exactly you mean by 3 Months?

Comment: Yes, its ok, just look at the TryParse() in the answer bellow, because its safer for parsing.

Comment: Please specify a locale when parsing the date. You probably want `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`. Else you'll most likely get problems when you run the program on a computer with a different locale from what you're used to.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A few things to think about:

- "Is date x earlier than 3 months before today" isn't the same as "today is more than 3 months later than date x"; you'll need to make sure you have the exact semantics you want.
- Consider what you want to do with the time component - are you interested in *dates* or dates *and times*? (Would you expect the condition evaluation to change based on the current time of day?)
- Consider time zones: are you interested in "today in the system's current time zone" or some fixed time zone?
- Depending on the source of the text data, you should *possibly* use `DateTime.TryParse` and you should *possibly* use `DateTime.ParseExact` or `DateTime.TryParseExact`, passing in the expected format (and culture)

Basically, there are various corner cases around date and time behaviour - you should explicitly think about all of these things (some of which are forced upon you if you use [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) instead of `DateTime`, btw :)

Regarding the first point, if the idea is that you get a trial period of three months from the installation date (or something similar), that suggests you should be *adding* three months to that instead.

I'd also change the variable name and get rid of the redundant parentheses, by the way:

```
DateTime installationDate = DateTime.Parse("1/5/2012 8:12:14 PM");
DateTime trialPeriodEnd = installationDate.AddMonths(3);
if (trialPeriodEnd > DateTime.Now)
{
   // do something
}
```

Assuming you're storing the installation date yourself somewhere, I would try to store it in some form which is less ambiguous - possibly even storing just a "ticks" value instead of a string. But assuming you *are* storing it yourself, you shouldn't need to use `TryParse` - it makes sense to go "bang" if you can't parse the value. I'd use `ParseExact`, probably with a [standard format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) of "o" (round trip).

Answer (score 3):

```
DateTime installdate ;

            if (DateTime.TryParse("1/5/2012 8:12:14 PM", out installdate))
            {
                if ((installdate < DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3))) { } 
            }
```

Tryparse is used so as to validate if the date passed in the parameter is valid or invalid

Comment: Since the install date is most likely machine written, using `Parse` is fine IMO. I'd treat it as a generic "My config is corrupted" error. The lack of specified culture is a much bigger flaw IMO.

Comment: Ya. You are absolutely right. But it's just for a precaution point of view to handle error if any....

Comment: @StackOverflowUser: If this is a date which is reasonably *expected* to be correct, than an exception is the appropriate response to it not being correct. `TryParse` is appropriate when it's *not* an exceptional situation if the value is wrong.

Comment: In my past project. My QA changed the date from registery somehow :)